# Cannot run an AVD (Emulator)

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

When I create and start an emulator in AVD manager. I am getting the following Error:

```
Starting emulator for AVD 'test_AVD'
Failed to create Context 0x3005
emulator: WARNING: Could not initialize OpenglES emulation, using software renderer.
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
```

Please don't mark this post as `duplicate`. I've already checked all similar posts. Each of them suggest an entirely different solution. But none of them worked for me.
Can anyone please help me fix this?

I am using: Win7

I downloaded ADT Bundle from here: http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html

### Edit:

Here are my AVD settings:

[image]

Comment: Could you at least mention on what platform (Win/Mac/Linux) you are trying to run on.

Comment: @MorrisonChang sorry for insufficient info. I've included it in the post now.

Comment: Are you using windows 8 ?
I'm having the same problem.

Comment: @Barakos I mentioned in OP that I was on Win7 when I had this problem. BTW, I preferred using my phone for testing instead of wasting more time to fix the emulator.

Answer (score 1):

i used to have problems with my emulator, the best thing i did was reinstalling eclipse's bundle all in one kit...

http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html

i advice you to just download (i think no installation required) this bundle- it has everything u need (emulator,sdk,...)

good luck sir :)

these are my properties in the AVDmanager. 
[image]

[image]

hopes this helps. let me know.

Comment: I've just downloaded the bundle from the same location. Still I am getting the error.

Comment: @Whops No Luck :-( In fact I am using a newer version. I have dofferent options on the create/edit AVD screen. I've added the screenshot of that screen in original post. May be some one would now be able to tell what are the appropriate settings to make AVD run properly.

Comment: try removing the snapshot check, and tell me if that worked our for you

Comment: it didn't work. I also tried un-checking other checboxes one by one. BTW, can it be because of some problem with the JDK? Because I remember last time the tutorial that I followed asked me to set some environment variable paths. I haven't set any paths this time yet. Can it be the problem?

Comment: I'm sry, i really dont know..
I really believe that if u uninstall everything and reinstall the bundle it might work.. if u did that already im sry, i cant really help you.. if u want u can ask specific questions about my paths and ill share screen shots..

Comment: Thanks for trying to help. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Just open your Emulator manually before open your android studio. I advice you to use nox android emulator or genymotion.